# How to get the value of selected radiobutton in gridview using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on wijgrid and I have given a radio button to html form.
I have used jquery to get the value of radio button and it is displying on the form but its not showing at grid.

I want to get the value of paramcode on selection of radio button and this value should display at wijgrid.My code is working fine and its showing the value but when I am saving the the data of form its not accepting radio button values inside the grid.

Please help ...Thanks Tina!!

This is my JSON (reformatted for legibility, but actually minified):

```
{
    "jsonWrapperforGrid": {
        "page": "1",
        "total": "2",
        "rows": [
            {
                "tenantId": 0,
                "paramType": "UserGender",
                "paramCode":"F", 
                "langCode":"en", 
                "paramValue":"Female"
            },
            {
                "tenantId": 0,
                "paramType": "UserGender",
                "paramCode": "M",
                "langCode": "en",
                "paramValue": "Male", 
                "paramBlob": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({ 
    url: "UserGender",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : "application/json",
    success: function (responce) { 
        if (responce.jsonWrapperforGrid.rows.length > 0) {
            $.each(responce.jsonWrapperforGrid.rows, function (i, entity) {  
                $('#gencom01').append(
                    $('<label />', { 'for': 'gender' + entity.paramValue,
                                     'text': entity.paramValue }),
                    $('<input />', { 'id': 'gender' + entity.paramCode,
                                     'type': 'radio', 
                                     'name': 'gender', 
                                     'value': entity.paramValue })
                    .click(function() {
                        var inputValue = $('input:radio:[name=+"gendernew"]:checked').val(entity.paramCode);
                        $("#gencom").val(entity.paramCode );
                    })
                );
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<body>  
  <div id="gencom01">
    <td><input id="gencom" style="width:205px ;" name="gendernew">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it really all your code?
If you start making ajax calls at load, maybe it's something you could have handled on the server side? But you probably have your reasons.

First you need to **use the `$(document).ready();` event**, you cannot start appending stuff to a tag that is probably not in your DOM yet.

Your **if statement is useless** `if (responce.jsonWrapperforGrid.rows.length > 0)` , your .each() loop will just not do anything if the length is 0, no need to test for that before.

Then even worse, you started declaring a .click() inside a .append(), while it might work, that looks a bit weird and can be source of many errors. It is usually easier to debug to **keep your DOM manipulation and your events separate**. And use .on(), more up to date.

I don't know your technology behind your AJAX call, but **parsing your JSON** into a real JS object can help : `var jsonData = $.parseJSON(responce);`

Thus, it's good practice to **make as little .append() as possible**, using it in a loop can take time. I'd advise saving your data in a variable and only at the end of your loop you can append everything.

And I don't know what this `<td>` is doing in your `<div>`.

Here is how your **code** could look like, I couldn't test anything since I don't know how your JSON looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/mgw/pankanis/admin/SysParameter?Paramtype=UserGender",
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "json",

        contentType : "application/json",
        success: function (responce)
        {
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(responce);
            var toAppend = "";
            $.each(jsonData.jsonWrapperforGrid.rows,function(i,entity)
            {
                toAppend += '<label for="gender'+entity.paramValue+'">'+entity.paramValue+'</label>';
                toAppend += '<input id="gender'+entity.paramCode+'" type="radio" name="gender" value="'+entity.paramValue+'">';
            });
            $('#gencom01').append(toAppend);
            $("#gencom01 input:not(#gencom)").on("click",function()
            {
                $("#gencom").val($(this).attr("id").substr(6)); // entity.paramCode
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ....I am working on html form where I have 8 fields and one of then is radio button which I want to use for gender field...I checked your code and its not giving the output....my code is working but its not saving the paramcode value to grid (UI site) {where rest of the field are apearing...} ...Please help ..I am new in jquery(Wijmo) ...Thanks Tina

Comment: I'm not sure your event can access a variable that is not in its scope.Does entity.paramCode have a value when you click? Try to use my line in your own event $("#gencom").val($(this).attr("id").substr(6));

Comment: @ GIl Zumbrunnen : I tried ur code but the problem is same ....Still its not accepting the radio button value....I have modify my question above..please recheck ...may be u get some clue...Thank you

Comment: @Tina Have you tried setting a type to your input tag? ie. type="text"

Comment: @ GIl Zumbrunnen : No I didn't try that.....Thats not my problem gil ...My problem is My code is working but its not accepting the radio button value ...The moment I am hitting any one of radio button it is not saving my data to grid (UIgrid){Location where I want to submit my radio button value}. Tina                                                        Gil please check my code below and try to test with html page

Comment: @Tina Take a look at your selector, it is very confusing : 'input:radio:[name=+"gendernew"]:checked' Your grid inputs have a name "gender", while the only one with name "gendernew is in your raw html, but it is not of a radio type, or any type actually. Try setting a type to this input and modify your selector accordingly.

Comment: @ GIl Zumbrunnen,if I will change the type it will change to the text box field which I don't want...    and gil if you are confusing about this 'input:radio:[name=+"gendernew"]:checked' ..please leave this part as I have given for testing purpose ....in place of this code ...(u can write simple alert(entity.paramCode also).....              I am not getting the code after .click event because I want to submit my paramCode value to grid (could you please provide that?).

Comment: @ GIl Zumbrunnen: Thank you very much for your help Gill....I got the solution .There is only I need to change the id type ...like : $("<input />").val(entity.paramCode ); this one and now its working ...Thanks Tina